# How to make a member deeply readonly?

Tags: c#, constants, readonly

I have a class which has a readonly member

```
class A
{
    public static readonly Student student = new Student("StudentName");
}
```

And the member student is not deeply readonly, I can

```
A.student.Name = "Another Name";
```

Student is a third-party class that I cannot change. How to make it deeply readonly?

Comment: Make it private and expose every property yourself via read-only properties.

Comment: "And the member student is not deeply readonly" well, I understand english is not your first language. But what do you mean by "deeply readonly"? Unclear.

Comment: @TomTom: he means that no one should be able to change the name of the student (or other properties) later.

Comment: wrap the class you dont own with a class you do own, and expose that

Comment: You can use a wrapper class. Or you can subclass the Student class and expose only the read only parts. This is still open to the subclass being cast back to a Student, of course, but this may be sufficient for your purposes, depending on how concerned you are regarding future misuse. Of course, someone could simply remove all your wrapper code and replace it with Student classes again as well. So, there are solutions available here, but there will always exist the possibility to misuse the solution. It's up to yourself which you consider best. Both techniques can be found in my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

You don't.  There's no magic keyword that would make not only the reference immutable, but the object referred to by it immutable.  You need to use an immutable object as the type of that field if you want to make it truly immutable.  You could potentially create a wrapper class that composes your mutable type, without exposing any of the mutation operators publicly, or create a new type that is comparable to the one that you have but that is immutable, but if you expose that existing type from this class there isn't anything you can do to stop someone from mutating it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Student` class should have it's properties setter `private`. If you have no control over the class, create a wrapper, which only has `private` setters.

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Student(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Or the wrapper:

```
public class StudentWrapper
{
    Student _student;

    public string Name { get { return _student.Name; } }

    public Student(Student student)
    {
        _student = student;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You could subclass the Student class and provide your own read only implementation from there, ensuring that each publicly accessible setter is final. It could still be cast back to a Student again, of course, but for your own development purposes, then you can ensure that it will be locally "read only".

Or you could wrap the student class in a class of your own, only allowing access to the getters.

Here's some example code to illustrate the methods I've described, given that some people don't seem to believe that it's possible...

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student student = new Student();
            student.Name = "Joe";

            StudentSubClass studentSubClassed = new StudentSubClass();
            studentSubClassed.Name = ""; // THIS LINE IS DISALLOWED FOR COMPILATION.

            StudentWrapper studentWrapped = new StudentWrapper(student);
            studentWrapped.Name = ""; // THIS LINE IS DISALLOWED FOR COMPILATION.
        }
    }

    class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class StudentSubClass : Student
    {
        public new string Name { get; private set; }
    }

    class StudentWrapper
    {
        private Student student;

        public StudentWrapper(Student student)
        {
            this.student = student;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.student.Name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, of course you can cast the subclassed instance back to a Student like so...

```
var newStudent = (Student)studentSubClassed;
newStudent.Name = "";
```

And this would allow access again, but given that it's you that's developing it, then you can ensure that it is at least "reasonably" readonly provided someone doesn't come back and cast it, which would defeat the point of what you're hoping to achieve with this development.

There is no cast iron method of ensuring future misuse of the subclassing technique, although it's a perfectly reasonable way of doing it, provided it's understood why it's being done, but with the wrapper technique, then you can ensure that your implementation will be unaffected by misuse. However, if the wrapped classes change in future, then you will have to amend your wrapper accordingly.

Another alternative would be to simply write your own implementation of the Student class as an Immutable class.

Comment: You cannot remove operations with a derived type, only add them.

Comment: You can with a wrapper class. There's always a way round restrictions.

Comment: Wrapping is not deriving.

Comment: Yes.  I know.  I said as much in my answer.  You, on the other hand, said to subclass it, which is very different, and *doesn't* work.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but it's still possible. You can subclass and provide your own overridden implementation of exposed signatures.

Comment: Yes, it's possible by means you didn't mention in your answer, and not possible with means you did mention in your answer.  So hopefully you see why this makes your answer wrong.

Comment: Read my answer. It mentions subclassing quite clearly.

Comment: That does not help. You can cast it and you can change it.

Comment: He's not looking for a cast iron method of preventing future misuse. He's looking for a way of making the objects reasonably readonly within the scope of a piece of development. And either subclassing or using a wrapper are the ways to do just that. They're not cast iron. Of course you can cast it back, but that would then defeat the point of what he's doing with this and it would then become quite obvious in the code that that's what's happened. It's a perfectly reasonable answer to what he's trying to achieve here. It would be unhelpful to state that it's not possible and leave it at that.

Comment: How do *you* know that he's okay with the object being cast up and then mutated?  What makes you so sure that that isn't a concern?  He's stated no such thing.  He asked how to make the field properly readonly, and your solution doesn't do that, it just asks people politely not to mutate it without actually stopping them.  Given that this is information he's exposing publicly, and not storing privately, it may well be *very* important that his assumption that it not be mutated not be violated.

Comment: Only the subclassing method is affected by that. Wrapping is not. And I've qualified that in my answer. It's still far preferable to give actual solutions to the given problem, than to say nothing can be done, which is extremely unhelpful. Something CAN be done with some caveats. I'm not making the assumption that he wants it cast iron. I'm giving him options and explaining the caveats to those options. It's up to him what course he then chooses to follow given the various solutions provided.